# When clicking a button the listener doesn't work

Tags: android, android-button

When clicking on the signout button it doesn't swap the activity to the home activity, I have tried testing it to see if it works by creating a toast, Yet the Toast doesn't show up either.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button signout, missions, profile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        signout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SignOut);
        signout.setOnClickListener(this);
        missions = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Missions);
        missions.setOnClickListener(this);
        profile = (Button)findViewById(R.id.profileBtn);
        profile.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.SignOut:
            {

                Intent i = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.profileBtn:{

            }
            case R.id.Missions:{

            }


        }
    }

}
```

Yet when I click on the signout button it does not swap to the home activity.

Answer (score 0):

add  @Override above onClick method and remove {} frame case:-

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){

        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.SignOut:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            case R.id.profileBtn:
            break;

            case R.id.Missions:
             break;


        }
    }
```

and match your id with your defined id in your xml file

Comment: I copied this to my project and ran it and still no luck. Even cleaned, rebuilt and restarted android studio

Answer (score 0):

If you want to end this MainActivity, you may call finish after you start the activity.
Like,

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method.

```
signout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```